# Not Displaying Spaces

Tags: c++, for-loop, nested-loops

I'm very new to c++ and everything in general. I dont understand why my code doesn't work:

```
#include <cstdio>

int main(){
 
int a;

scanf("%d", &a);

for(int i = 1; i < a; i++){
 printf(" ");

}

printf("*");

}
```

what I'm trying to do is make the number of spaces as the value inputted by the user minus and add a * at the end so if a = 10 :

```
     *
```

but when I try it the spaces don't show.
Ideally what I'm trying to do is get an output something like:

```
   *
  **
 ***
****
```

The length depends on user input if it was 10 then the spaces would be 9 and the * at the end would be the tenth.

Comment: You're missing a `,` in the scanf call, I don't see how this could even compile. There are just way too many errors in the code you posted. Please: [mcve]

Comment: Why are you writing C and not C++?

Comment: thank you, sorry if my question and the way I worded things were unclear I also made a lot of spelling mistakes.

Comment: For a [mre], you should divide your code into two pieces: getting a value from the user and producing your output. If you are confident that you are correctly getting the value from the user, then replace `int a;

scanf("%d", &a);` with `int a = 10; // User-provided in real code`.

Comment: *"when I try it the spaces don't show."* -- When I ran the code, it produced spaces followed by an asterisk. Older versions of the question had code that wouldn't compile, which technically means the spaces don't show, but neither would the asterisk show. So there is a mismatch between the text and the code. Please make your question consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use 3 for-loops (two of them nested inside one). The parent for loop for each row. And the nested two are for spaces and stars.

```
#include <cstdio>
int main()
{

    int a;

    scanf("%d", &a);

    for(int i=1; i<a; i++)
    {
        for(int j=i; j<a; j++)
            printf(" ");
        for(int k=0; k<i; k++)
            printf("*");

        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

You will get your desired output if you put the value 5 for a, i.e., a=5.

To learn more in detail, you can follow this link [star patterns in c](https://www.educba.com/star-patterns-in-c/)

Your code may contain many errors. That's understandable, cause you are new to C/C++. Try problem-solving in [beecrowd](https://www.beecrowd.com.br/judge/en/problems/index/1) to improve your problem-solving capabilities and learn C/C++ in a better way. These errors will automatically go away day by day as you progress. But the secret is to practice and never give up. **Good luck!**